# Delay on Java for 2 seconds

Tags: java, key, delay, label

I want to have a delay between two labels. Have you an idea? I give an example below to be more easy what i need. Thank you

```
//wait for 2 seconds
jLabel1.setIcon(leftIcon);
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && k==0)
{
    //wait for 2 seconds
    jLabel2.setIcon(leftIcon);
    k++;
}
else  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && k==1)
{
    System.out.print("\nup up up\n");
    //wait for 2 seconds
    jLabe3.setIcon(leftIcon);
    k++;
}
```

To be more specific:

So, I want to have a frame, and every two seconds we see a different image.At the begin,you can see the first image for a second.After,the first image closes,and after two seconds open another image..

Answer (score 1):

For Swing time delays, use a Swing Timer. You can find a link to the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). In the Timer's ActionListener, you can set your JLabel's icon and also increment your counter.

As an aside, this is unclear to me:

> I want to have a delay between two labels

You can't "delay" a component. I am assuming that you mean you want to delay the display of ImageIcons in a JLabel, correct?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding..
So, I want to have a frame, and every two seconds we see a different image.At the begin,you can see the first image for a second.After,the first image closes,and after two seconds open another image..Is it better?

Comment: @user2933161: update your original question with this information. Consider telling even more information as well. But yes, your solution is to use a Swing Timer. Please check the link.